# NullPointerException in the service when the app is deleted from the recent apps

Tags: android

I've been trying to check what the user might do and I catched a NullPointerException in my service , when the user sets a notification so my service can notify the user when the time comes and then the user shuts the app from the recent apps , it crashes , I did handle the error by try and catch , but the problem is how can I get the information that was passed by intent to the service ? and most importantly how to solve this problem ?

this is the error:

```
08-04 13:28:04.863: E/AndroidRuntime(3380): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service 
com.example.myapp.Service_reminder@b4ef5228 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I've searched and found:

[Android service crashes after app is swiped out of the recent apps list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18612880/android-service-crashes-after-app-is-swiped-out-of-the-recent-apps-list)

when I've gone to the android guide about the foreground service it says that one of the functions is deprecated.

Comment: Does your service return start_sticky on your onStartCommand?

Comment: @jaytj95 , yes I'm using return START_STICKY